# Laravel 8 insert data to multiple connected tables

Tags: mysql, laravel-8, relationship, laravel-relations

I have two tables: (Table A & TableB).

Table A = id(primary), name, email

Table B = user_id(foreign(id)), column1, column2

**What I need to do is:**

1. Insert a row in Table A.
2. Verify the insertion.
3. Insert row in Table B & store Table A (id) in Table B (user_id).

Currently, I'm handling it like the following.

```
//  Create a row in Table A
$createUser = UserModel::create($userData);

// Verifying insertion of the by checking if id is set
if (isset($createUser['id'])) {
    $adminData = [
        'name' => $info['adminName'],
        'user_id' => $createUser['id'],   // insert into user_id  
        'email_address' => $info['adminEmail'],
        'contact_number' => $info['adminNumber'],
    ];

    $createAdmin = AdminsModel::create($adminData);
}
```

I'm looking for a better way for multiple chained tables to avoid an if-else ladder.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with what you are doing. But you can also use [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships).

First define this method in the UserModel.

```
/**
 * Get the admin associated with the user.
 */
public function admin()
{
    return $this->hasOne(AdminsModel::class);
}
```

And use it like so

```
$createUser = UserModel::create($userData);
$createUser->admin->create([
    'name' => $info['adminName'],
    'email_address' => $info['adminEmail'],
    'contact_number' => $info['adminNumber'],
]);
```